# How can I get search with pagination in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

In laravel I've only got pagination, but I want pagination with searching.

Here is my code for pagination.

```
$leads = DB::table('leads')->join('states','leads.state','=','states.id')->join('districts','leads.district','=','districts.id')->join('users','leads.userid','=','users.id')->select('leads.*','states.name as sname','districts.name as dname','users.name as uname')->orderBy('leads.id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
```

I have tried pagination with searching but it's not working properly.

Here is the my code:

```
$leads = DB::table('leads')->join('states','leads.state','=','states.id')->join('districts','leads.district','=','districts.id')->join('users','leads.userid','=','users.id')->select('leads.*','states.name as sname','districts.name as dname','users.name as uname')->where('leads.phoneno', 'like', "%$search%")->paginate(10);
```

Please can any one can help me with where I've made a mistake?

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working properly?

Comment: Yes.pagination is not working. all pages loading first 10 records only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$leads = DB::table('leads')->join('states','leads.state','=','states.id')->join('districts','leads.district','=','districts.id')->join('users','leads.userid','=','users.id')->select('leads.*','states.name as sname','districts.name as dname','users.name as uname')->where('leads.phoneno', 'like', '%'.$search. '%')->paginate(10);
```